# cloud9 htaccess

Tags: html

Cloud9を利用して開発しようと思うのですがSSIを利用してローカルで作業していました。
cloud9に情報をアップしましたが、うまくhtaccessが効かず、SSIを利用できていません。

どうすればよいか、分かりますか？